# /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:139:in `chdir': No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: ios, fastlane, bitbucket-pipelines, fastlane-deliver

I am using **ruby 2.7 docker image** on **bibtbucket pipelines**
ruby version : ruby 2.7.8p225 (2023-03-30 revision 1f4d455848) [x86_64-linux]
this is my code :

```
- gem install fastlane
- export LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8
- export LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
- fastlane ios release_to_app_store
```

The error comes with the last command executed: `fastlane ios release_to_app_store`
This is the error:

```
+------+---------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | app_store_connect_api_key | 0           |
|    | deliver                   | 1           |
+------+---------------------------+-------------+
[19:04:26]: fastlane finished with errors
[19:04:26]: Error accessing file, this might be due to fastlane's directory handling
[19:04:26]: Check out https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/#directory-behavior for more details
**/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:139:in `chdir': No such file or directory @ dir_chdir -  (Errno::ENOENT)**
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:139:in `cd'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/itunes_transporter.rb:649:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/itunes_transporter.rb:791:in `upload'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/deliver/lib/deliver/runner.rb:219:in `upload_binary'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/deliver/lib/deliver/runner.rb:65:in `run'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/upload_to_app_store.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:263:in `block (2 levels) in execute_action'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:69:in `execute_action'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:255:in `block in execute_action'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `chdir'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `execute_action'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:157:in `trigger_action_by_name'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:159:in `method_missing'
    from Fastfile:53:in `block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in `block in execute'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `chdir'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:47:in `cruise_lane'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:36:in `handle'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:110:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:187:in `call'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:157:in `run'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/runner.rb:444:in `run_active_command'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fastlane-2.214.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:124:in `run!'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/commander-
```

and this is my fastfile:

```
app_store_connect_api_key(
      key_id: ENV['APP_STORE_KEY_ID'],
      issuer_id: ENV['APP_STORE_ISSUER_ID'],
      key_content: ENV['APP_STORE_FASTLANE_API_AUTH_KEY_BASE64'],
      is_key_content_base64: true
    )
    
    deliver(
      app_identifier: app_identifier,
      username: apple_id,
      force: true,
      app_version: "0.2.24",
      ipa: ipa_path,
      submit_for_review: true,
      force: true,
      skip_metadata: true,
      skip_screenshots: true
    )
```

Thank you!